# Custom blocks inside TextField

Tags: flutter

For last several years I develop an online-CAT (computer-assisted translation) project. Frontend is based on AngularJS, which is pretty outdated to date. So I'm looking for some modern interface-building solution and Flutter seems to be very attractive.

But I have one piece of project that (theoretically) can be hard to reproduce in Flutter - the text editor for translations:

https://monosnap.com/file/jZXEuu4M89gQOgi0ys1hmQrMsPboBm

After user uploads some document (like DOCX), backend parses all the text data from it and hides all the formatting data behind tags. Top block's code right now looks like this:

```
<tag i='1'> You may distribute it and/or modify it under the terms of either the GNU 
General Public License (</tag><tag i='2'>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html</tag>),
version 3 or later, or the Creative Commons Attribution License (<tag i='2'>
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/</tag>), version 4.0 or later.
```

And the second one, which is div contenteditable looks like this:

```
<hr l="" i="1">Вы можете распространять этот документ<hr r="" i="1"> и/или изменять
его в соответствии с условиями лицензии GNU General Public License 
(http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), версии 3 или более поздней или  Creative 
Commons Attribution License (<hr l="" i="2">http://creativecommons.org/
licenses/by/4.0/<hr r="" i="2">), версии 4 или более поздней.
```

So, opening tag `<tag i='1'>` equals `<hr l="" i="1">` and closing tag `</tag>` equals `<hr r="" i="1">`. And there are some non-paired (single) tags presented as `<tag i='1' />` and `<hr s="" i="1">`

So, right now I have two main questions:

1. Is there a proper way to create non-selectable elements that can be deleted as a single piece even if the tag's label will be a multi-character string (`<tag i="gm150">`)?
2. Is there a way to create custom background shapes for such elements? I've already discovered that I can create rectangle-shaped backgrounds using Paint class:

```
    child: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: 'Hello '),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'beautiful',
            style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()
                ..color = Colors.blue
              )
            ),
          TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

But I'm looking for something like this:
[image: preferred result]

Answer (score 1):

You can insert any widget (in rich text) using a `WidgetSpan`, that's for displaying the text,

For text editing you will need to implement it using some workaround since  the WidgetSpan api isn't supported for TextFields yet(it's a work in progress by the flutter team checkout more about the issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30688)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              children: <InlineSpan>[
                TextSpan(text: 'Hello '),
                // use A custom painted object
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow.shade700,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text('TAG'),
                  ),
                ),
                TextSpan(text: 'beautiful'),
                // use A custom painted object
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow.shade700,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text('TAG'),
                  ),
                ),
                TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]